Compare variance explained between 4 x 300 multiple linear regressions
I calculated four different multiple linear regressions (model 1-4), each with a different set of independent variables. Model 2 contains all the independent variables of model 1, plus some extra. Model 3 contains all independent variables of model 2 plus some more and so on. I want to find out whether adding more independent variables led to a significantly better prediction of the dependent variable’s variance. 
Now here’s the catch: Each of the models not only contains one multiple regression but 300, each regression with a different dependent variable. The 300 dependent variables are the same in all four models, it’s just the independent variables that are becoming more from model 1 to model 4.
Now what would be a simple way to compare the variance explained by the four models if each model contains 300 multiple regression? Would it be an option to

calculate an average adjusted R2 for each model, i.e.  R2(model1) = [R2 (first regression, model 1) + R2(second regression, model 1)+….R2(300th regression, model 1)] / 300? 

OR

sum up all adjusted R2s per model, i.e. R2(model1) = R2 (first regression, model 1) + R2(second regression, model 1)+….R2(300th regression, model 1)

 to get a „total R2“ per model and then compare these with an F-test?
Also/Alternatively: I cannot find any credible and understandable sources how to get this „total R2“, do you know a paper or key words that would help me? 
Thank you all very much for your help!

one approach would be to view your 300 models as being a single model with interaction terms against dummy variables, and subsequently to use standard R2/adjusted R2s.

Isn't the 1st option just the 2nd one divided by 300? If so, they are equivalent.

At bottom, you are asking us how to make tradeoffs among 300 sets of models, one for each dependent variable.  There's no way we can answer that in general, because it depends on what those variables mean to you and what decisions you will be making with this analysis: it's no different than asking us whether apples are better than oranges.  Perhaps that's why it's so difficult to run down an authority on the matter!
